SpringBoot 3.2.6 Application - Server not started
I downloaded a simple SpringBoot application v3.2.6 from https://start.spring.io/ for Java version 17
When I tried to start the application, I see the below output,
12:17:42: Executing ':DemoApplication.main()'...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :DemoApplication.main()

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.6)

2024-06-16T12:17:44.680+05:30  INFO 12032 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.9 with PID 12032 
2024-06-16T12:17:44.684+05:30  INFO 12032 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-06-16T12:17:45.602+05:30  INFO 12032 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.432 seconds (process running for 1.802)

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
12:17:45: Execution finished ':DemoApplication.main()'.


usually, when I run the Springboot application, the server starts in port 8080 and then I see the server started message, but in this case, the server did not get started, but the Build was Successful, not sure what I was missing.

What command you used to start application?

I started from my IntelliJ IDE, I just missed the below dependency,
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

Really it started and then finished as we see from the log. You have to include some dependency to make the application listen on 8080.
For example you can include Spring Web component

My Bad, thank you for pointing out...
